# Use redis cache with EF Core

Tags: caching, .net-core, redis, entity-framework-core

guys.

I use EF Core with caching. The current cache realization needs objects to support the `IMemoryCache`  interface.
But all distributed caches realized IDistributionCache and there is no direct way to say DbContext to use, for example, Redis Cache instead of an in-memory cache. 
Are there any existing solutions for the Redis cache integration? Or I must realize my own proxy between `IDistributionCache` and `IMemoryCache`.

My current .NET version is the .NET 5.0 - preview 4.

Thank you.

Comment: Just curious, did you check the dot net core performance article on caching by Mohsin Nasir and Steve Smith? It looks like it covers what you are asking. [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Answer (score 1):

I am looking into this also.  You might want to look at
https://github.com/VahidN/EFCoreSecondLevelCacheInterceptor

Comment: Hello. Yes, I've already started using this library.